# POST http://localhost:3307/insert 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to add a client here and I get this error. POST http://localhost:3307/insert 500 (Internal Server Error) . I don't know exactly what is the problem.  Maybe I make something wrong in my code, or maybe is from something else.
https://prnt.sc/wfueig

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");
const { listenerCount } = require("process");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//Int a = 1;


const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password: "123456",
    database: "clau"
    //port: "1521",
});

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {

const username = req.body.username
const password = req.body.password

db.query(
    "INSERT INTO USERS (username,password) VALUES(?,?);",
    [username, password],
    (err, result) => {
            console.log(err); 
   
}
);
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username
const password = req.body.password

db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = ? and password = ?",
    [username, password],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            res.send({err: err});
        }
        if(result.length > 0) {
                res.send(result);
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "Wrong username/password combination!"});
            }
        }
);

});

class DbService{
    static getDbServiceInstance(){
        return instance ? instance: new DbService();
    }

    async insertNewClient(firstname,lastname,phone,email,city) {
        try{
            const insertId = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
                const query = "INSERT INTO client (firstName,lastName,Phone,Email,City) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";

                resolve()
                connection.query(query,[firstname,lastname,phone,email,city],(err,result)=>{
                    if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
                    resolve(result.insertId);
                })
            });

            //console.log(insertId);
            return response;
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

}
app.post('/insert', (request, response) => {
    const { firstname, lastname, phone, email, city } = request.body;
    console.log("in insert");
    db.query(
        "INSERT INTO client (firstName,lastName,Phone,Email,City) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);",
        [firstname, lastname, phone, email, city],
        (err, result) => {
            console.log(err);

        }
    );
    const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();

    const result = db.insertNewName(firstname,lastname,phone,email,city);

    result
        .then(data => response.json({ success: true }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});


app.listen(3307, () => {
    console.log("Running server ");
});
```

(****************This is for requested details spam *********** OFF TOPIC)

When you picture mountain climbers scaling Mount Everest, what probably comes to mind are teams of climbers with Sherpa guides leading them to the summit, equipped with oxygen masks, supplies and tents. And in most cases you'd be right, as 97 per cent of climbers use oxygen to ascend to Everest's summit at 8,850 metres above sea level. The thin air at high altitudes makes most people breathless at 3,500 metres, and the vast majority of climbers use oxygen past 7,000 metres. A typical climbing group will have 8–15 people in it, with an almost equal number of guides, and they'll spend weeks to get to the top after reaching Base Camp.

But ultra-distance and mountain runner Kilian Jornet Burgada ascended the mountain in May 2017 alone, without an oxygen mask or fixed ropes for climbing.

Oh, and he did it in 26 hours.

With food poisoning.

Comment: I declared above const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance(); db before use it It's not from it

Comment: In your `app.post("/insert|",....)` code block you refer to db in `db.query(..)` before you define `const db ...` in the subsequent line. I suspect that may be causing your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What has the last part (Mount Everest) to do with your question? To improve your questions, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You should have to move your `const db = dbService.getDbServiceInstance();` from line 96 to line 87.

[image]